# The current path, photos/, didn't match any of these

Tags: django

I'm trying to get an app running in django but I encounter this error: The current path, photos/, didn't match any of these, even though I could not figure which part of the code is problematic. Here is my code:

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
  return HttpResponse("<h>This is the main page</h>")
```

urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from photoapp import views

urlpatterns = [
path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

main urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('photos/', include('photoapp.urls')),
]
```

Settings:

```
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'photoapp.apps.PhotoappConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

 MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'photop.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'photop.wsgi.application'
```

I have tried using a trailing slash after photos too but the issue persists.

Comment: That code should work, can you post the full error log and the full URL you are requesting?

Comment: Page not found (404)
Request Method:  GET
Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/photos/

Using the URLconf defined in photop.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    admin/
    photos/ admin/

The current path, photos/, didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.

Comment: I'm also getting this in command prompt: WARNINGS:
?: (urls.W005) URL namespace 'admin' isn't unique. You may not be able to reverse all URLs in this namespace.

Comment: Have you tried adding a trailing slash `/` at the end of the request: `<url>/photos/` instead of `<url>/photos`?  Can you also post your `settings.py` please?

Comment: I just edited my post to contain the settings.py code too. and yes I have used a trailing slash, no success.